# Windows 7 only finding Folders

Tags: windows-7

Don't know if this if the right place to ask this kinda question, sorry in advance if it is the wrong place.

I got a new laptop with Win 7, and its the first PC I own with Win 7, so I'm a bit new to it. Recently I was looking for a file on my external HDD, and after being asked to index the drive, I said "What the heck" and said yes.

However, now Win 7 will only find Folders, not files. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

P.S I know that its not finding files as EVERY search i do has only folders, and any search i do for files (with the full file name) will return a "Cant find anything"

EDIT

Fixed Problem by saying "Dont use the Index" but this begs the question, whats wrong with the index?

Comment: all i know so far, is the indexer works very slowly in the background, give it some time. and the search has to be re-learned all over again.  Check out some of these threads, each one a little different. http://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bwindows7%5D+search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay click on your Windows Icon at the bottom left, type in find and fix problems with windows search, click on that and let it run.
You should see the option 
"files don't appear in my search results"

Comment: That didnt fix it. I think because its only for my external drive. I can still find files when seraching any where but the external